# Shimano Revoshift repair

Tags: repair, gears, shimano

My bike has a grip shift (Shimano revoshift) which isn't shifting through all 8 gears.  Even with the gear cable removed (it recently broke) it will only shift through half of the gear numbers and some blanks.  It is almost as if the number dial has slipped around the shifter.

It still sort of works ok but I can't use all of the gears.

Is it just a broken shifter that needs replacing or is it something that can be fixed?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

KR,
Pappaun

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how much you value your time. Taking one of these to pieces and putting it back together again is do-able but may not give you the fix needed, whereas, buy the new part and it might save you time.

To give it a go, type in 'revoshift' into http://techdocs.shimano.com/techdocs/index.jsp and pull up your manual.

And personally, if I were you, I would give it a go.

Comment: Definitely worth it - worst case it still doesn't work afterwards. Just be aware that there are a couple of small springs in there. Use the ZAMM approach in a clean area, because finding a dark coloured 2mmx3mmx3mm spring in a dirty workshop is pretty impossible. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_and_the_Art_of_Motorcycle_Maintenance)

Comment: Thanks, might give it a go when I've got a bit of spare time then.

Comment: Typing "revoshift" into the Shimano tech docs page shows no results.

Answer (score 1):

I have found grip shifts to have more problems over time than trigger shifters.  If you plan on riding this particular bike for several years, I recommend swapping out the revoshift in favor of comparably priced shimano trigger shifters.  Since you are even considering taking apart the shifter, I believe you will be able to install new shifters, cables and housing.  Remember that new cables will stretch quickly, so if you choose to change shifters, be prepared to adjust the cable lengths after the first couple rides.

If you would like to fix the shifter you have, make sure to take a picture of the shifter mechanism when you open it up before starting to work on it.  Then make an outline of what you see on a piece of paper and tape to it the screws you remove in their respective locations.  Make new such outlines for each level of shifter as you remove more pieces.  This way you can avoid losing tiny screws and springs and other pieces and you will know what goes where when you try to reassemble the shifter.