# Shimano Revo Shift Gives No Clicks

Tags: repair, shimano, shifter

I have a problem with my shifter. My bike is using Shimano Revo Shift(gripshift) RS-35 (see my picture).  The one shifting the front derailer (the left shifter) does not click when I turn it but it can still shift the cable.  How do I repair it?  I don't even know how do open up the shifter in the first place.

[image: Shimano RS-35]

Comment: Related, or possible duplicate?http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/4118/1259

Comment: Does Shimano provide some sort of maintenance guide for fixing problem like this?  I did search their site but cannot really find any detailed info about the internal working of their gripshifters.

Comment: What clocks do you mean? It's not an index shifter.

Comment: @Alexander Shimano RS35 non-indexed (friction) front shifters, as the one in the picture, still click when twisted. They simply have multiple smaller clicks instead of three larger clicks. Having one that works smoothly is not normal.

Comment: Personally I'd replace this shifter with a thumb shifter, (aka a pod shifter).  Revoshits don't have a good reputation.  You can leave the left-side one as-is if it still works.  Note your grips will also need replacing because they'll be too short.

Answer (score 5):

Opening it is simple. Remove the grip, grasp the portion of the shifter that turns to shift, and rotate it back like you are shifting, while pulling it towards the center of the bar.

Putting it back together is not simple, and will likely not happen without assistance. Ask your LBS to show you the procedure if you want to learn.

If not, ask them to fix it. It will like require replacing the pawl spring (snoopy spring) inside it, which creates the click, and holds the shifter to a particular gear. It may require replacing the shifter body, depending on what is broken inside.

1. [Shimano Installation guide](http://techdocs.shimano.com/media/techdocs/content/cycle/SI/Nexus/ShiftLever/SL-3S35/6E80B-001_SL-3S35-E-ENG_v1_m56577569830655182.pdf)
2. [Shimano tech docs for RevoShift 3 speed](http://techdocs.shimano.com/media/techdocs/content/cycle/EV/bikecomponents/SL/EV-SL-3S35-E-1908_v1_m56577569830609195.pdf)
3. [Other styles of RevoShift Tech Docs](http://techdocs.shimano.com/techdocs/blevel.jsp)

The third link takes you to a tech doc page. It's java, so I can't link to the search directly. Type RevoShift in the search box.

Comment: Thx, another question, is there any maintenance guide describing the internal working of the grip shifter like its ratchet mechanism? I mean even the LBS somehow need a way to know about this.

Comment: See my edit above

Comment: Friction shifters don't have pawl springs, do they?

Answer (score 5):

From the picture, it looks like you have a friction shifter rather than an indexed shifter. Indexed shifters click, and friction shifters move smoothly. For a rear derailleur, you would almost always want indexed shifting because the cogs are so close together. For a crankset with 3 chainrings, friction shifting can be handy for fine-tuning the position of the front derailleur.

Comment: Yeah, the word "friction" on the shifter is a clue.

Comment: No. Shimano RS35 non-indexed (friction) front shifters, as the one in the picture, still click when twisted. They simply have multiple smaller clicks instead of three larger clicks. Having one that works smoothly is not normal.

Comment: @AnT 'not normal' says it should be repaired? It changes gears therefor doing it's work. What is bad with it?

Answer (score 1):

Likely the pawl has gotten gummed up, but can't help you with disassembly.  (It's not unheard of for the LBS repair guy to just spray lube into the shifter in this case, to try to free it up.)

But try this link: http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/shift-levers-shifters

Comment: is easy to disassemble, everything rests with the joints between the pieces of black plastic, need such gentleness and first understand how the pieces are stuck. I highly recommend you first remove the steel cable and analazzare the piece sitting at a table!

Answer (score 0):

Friction shifters have no clicks. If there's chain rub, simply move the shifter a little.

Comment: No. Shimano RS35 non-indexed (friction) front shifters, as the one in the picture, still click when twisted. They simply have multiple smaller clicks instead of three larger clicks. Having one that works smoothly is not normal.